# load my facebook username and picture in HTML Page

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

I m developing and android application using phonegap . I m follwing this tutorial https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/tree/962eb0a1c07935ff813e28aa9eaa5581f2e10416  and i m succesfully connecting to facebook in Phonegap and i m displaying my Facebook username and Picture in my (Index.html) and sending my informations to the server.
In this page (index.html) , i have a button that let me go to another HTML Page(Profile.html). I m trying to display my facebook informations to this page (Profile.html) as well as the (Index.html)

Here is the code in my JS File that let me display  my informations after a connect to facebook in my Indx.HTML Page and let me also send these informations to the server:

```
function handleStatusChange(session) 
{
 console.log('Got the user\'s session: ' + JSON.stringify(session));
 alert('Got the user\'s session: ' + JSON.stringify(session));

if (session.authResponse) 
 {
//document.body.className = 'connected';

//Fetch user's id, name, and picture
FB.api('/me', 
{
  fields: 'name, picture,first_name,last_name,email'
},
function(response) 
{
  if (!response.error) 
  {
    document.body.className = 'connected';

    user = response;

    console.log('Got the user\'s name and picture: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
    console.log('FB name, ' + response.name);
    console.log(('FB picture, ' + response.picture.data.url));
   // alert('Fb Id,'+response.id);
    //alert('Email'+response.email);
   // alert('FB Last name'+response.first_name);
   // alert('FB name, ' + response.last_name);



    //Update display of user name and picture
    if (document.getElementById('user-name')) 
    {
      document.getElementById('user-name').innerHTML = user.name;
    }
    if (document.getElementById('user-picture')) 
    {
      document.getElementById('user-picture').src = user.picture.data.url;
    }

    var callDataLogin = JSON.stringify({'serviceName':"global_functions", 'methodName':'login',"parameters":[response.id,response.last_name,response.first_name,response.email]});
    $.post('Server URL', callDataLogin, function(resp){}).done(function(data) 
    {               
        console.log(data);
        //alert(data);
        //alert(" Send User Facebook info to server , Login");
    });               
  }
  else 
  {
    document.body.className = 'not_connected';
    console.log('Error getting user info: ' + JSON.stringify(response.error));

    if (response.error.error_subcode && response.error.error_subcode == "458") 
    {
      setTimeout(function() 
              {
        alert("The app was removed. Please log in again.");
      }, 0);              
    }
    logout();         
  }

  clearAction();
});
}
else  {
 document.body.className = 'not_connected';

 clearAction();
 }   
 }
```

And here is the code in my Index.html page that let me display my Facebook User Informations:

```
<div id="page-root" class="page">
    <div class="show_when_connected">
    <div id="welcome"><img id="user-picture" /><br /><span id="user-name"></span></div>
    </div>
```

I also add this code to my Profile.html Page to display my facebook User Informations

```
<div id="page-root" class="page">
    <div class="show_when_connected">
    <div id="welcome"><img id="user-picture" /><br /><span id="user-name"></span></div>
    </div>
```

But it s not displaying anything in my Profile.html as in my Index.html
Thanks for your help

////////////////////////////////////////UPDATE/////////////////////////////////////////////

in my js file here is the code that i put

```
<script>
  //get the id
    var getFbId=sessionStorage.getItem('Fbid');
   //set the id html 
   document.getElementById('idget').innerHTML =getFbId;

   var getFbName=sessionStorage.getItem('FBName');
   //set the Name html 
   document.getElementById('Nameget').innerHTML =getFbName;

  var getFbPicture=sessionStorage.getItem('FBPicture');
  //set the Picture html 
  document.getElementById('Pictureget').innerHTML =getFbPicture;

 </script>
```

and in my Profile.html here is the code that i used:

```
<div id="idget"></div>
<div id="Nameget"></div>
<img id="Pictureget">
```

Comment: Which part is wont work.

Comment: All of this work but when i copy this code in my another HTML Page(Profile.html) to display my Facebook User Info as in the first HTML Page it isn't showing anything:
 <div id="page-root" class="page">
        <div class="show_when_connected">
        <div id="welcome"><img id="user-picture" /><br /><span id="user-name"></span></div>
        </div>

Comment: The Problem That i can't display my Username and picture in another HTML Page as i do in the first HTML Page

Comment: Can you please edit your question with your needs specifically.

Comment: In order to dispaly another html page either you can use session storage or local storage in your app.

Comment: wait i wll show an example for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just set your fb credentials in localstorage/session storage after this you can retrieve in any page that you want.

function(response) 
    {

```
    if (!response.error) 
      {
        document.body.className = 'connected';

        user = response;

        console.log('Got the user\'s name and picture: ' + JSON.stringify(response));
        console.log('FB name, ' + response.name);
        console.log(('FB picture, ' + response.picture.data.url));
       //set the id in session storage/localstorage
       sessionStorage.setItem('Fbid',response.id);
      //For localstorage
      window.localStorage.setItem( 'Fbid', response.id);
       }
}
```

For get this value in another html page by this way

```
    //get the id from session
     var getFbId=sessionStorage.getItem('Fbid');
   //get the id from localstorage
   var fromLocalStorage=window.localStorage.getItem( 'Fbid' );
    //set the id html 
    document.getElementById('idget').innerHTML =getFbid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, it's working , but two last question please,when i session storage my facebook picture and show it like this <img  id="Pictureget" > it's showing the url link but not the image and second question  how can i clear the id when i logout from facebook. Because now i m displaying the informations in profile.html but when i logout facebook user informations are always displaying . Thanks a lot again

Comment: Use session storage instead of local storage. session storage destroys all the variable when app exit.

Comment: i used a session storage , but when i logout my session variable are always showing

Comment: <script>
  //get the id
    var getFbId=sessionStorage.getItem('Fbid');
   //set the id html 
   document.getElementById('idget').innerHTML =getFbId;
   
   var getFbName=sessionStorage.getItem('FBName');
   //set the Name html 
   document.getElementById('Nameget').innerHTML =getFbName;
   
   var getFbPicture=sessionStorage.getItem('FBPicture');
   //set the Picture html 
   document.getElementById('Pictureget').innerHTML =getFbPicture;
    </script>

Comment: On logout remove the session variable by this way `sessionStorage.removeItem( 'Fbid');`

Comment: Really Thanks a lot , everything is working fine , i can now remove my session variable when i logout and when i login i can get then in my Profile.html Page , but i have only one thing , i can't display my picture it's showing me an url not the image. Can you please see the Update part in my post above. You saved me Thanks you so much

Comment: Yes , it's showing me the url of my Facebook Profile Picture but not the picture

Comment: change innerHTML to src like this `document.getElementById('Pictureget').src =getFbPicture;`

Comment: Thanks a loooot user2804362 for everything, Everything is working fine :)